# Erroneous compilation of the glossary entry corresponding to symbol `|||'

Tags: symbols, footnotes, glossaries

I need to define the symbol `|||` in my list of symbols. Then, it must be called from the caption of a figure and be displayed in a footnote. The following `MWE` illustrates the problem I've encountered.

My main file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[nogroupskip]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries
\loadglsentries{gloss-symb}

%For applied indentation to the glossary
\newglossarystyle{mylong}{%
    \setglossarystyle{long}%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{\dimexpr 2cm-\tabcolsep}p{0.8\hsize}}}
        {\end{longtable}}%
}

\begin{document}

\printnoidxglossary[sort=def,style=mylong,title={List of Symbols}]
\printnoidxglossary[type=symbols,sort=use]

\input{myChap}

\end{document}
```

My chapter file:

```
\kant[1] 

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}
    \caption{Here is the caption\protect\footnotemark.}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{$n$-ary operator `\gls{compose}' represents XXX.}

\kant[1]
```

My glossary file:

```
\newglossaryentry{compose}{name={|||},description={$n$-ary composition operator}}
```

As the following output shows, the symbol is not correctly printed in the footnote, nor in the list of symbols:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?...

Comment: You need `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, otherwise a wrong font encoding is used for `|||`. I suggest to use the `symbol` key also for the `|||` instead of `name`, that's why `glossaries` provides symbol as an extra key by default

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Thanks. Your comment resolved the problem. If you add an answer to the question, I would accept it.

Comment: @Roboticist This is almost surely a duplicate.

Comment: @egreg -- although the cited duplicate does mention the "interchangeability" between an em-dash and a vertical bar, this question appears to be asking explicitly about a triple vertical bar.  for that use, it would be much better to choose a command-based representation.  there are several to choose from, as shown in the [comprehensive symbols list](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/).

Comment: @Roboticist If that's a math symbol, why doesn't you use it a such?

Comment: @egreg: actually it is a math symbol, and I had designed a version of it by stacking a `\parallel` and a `|` using `stackengine` package. However, finally, I found out that this simple non-math symbol is both simpler to use and more beautiful for my application. Nevertheless, I bet the comprehensive list would contain something like this.